# Impact of underpowered speakers

Tags: amplifier, resistance, speakers, watts

I have an Onkyo TX-8220 Stereo Receiver and a pair of Polk Audio TSi400s.

The receiver specs:

> With 8 ohm loads, both channels driver, [...] rated 45 watts per channel minimum RMS power.

The speaker specs:

> Nominal Impedance: 8 ohms
> Power Handling (per channel): 20 watts → 200 watts

Clearly, the receiver is underpowered.

I realize this means it won't be able to drive the speakers at their full volume. But could this cause other problems such as loss of sound quality or damage to either the amplifier or the speakers?

Comment: This is not a real "electronics" question, this is a connection question. You better ask such things on an audio forum.

Comment: @Codebeat: Too bad I couldn't find an audio forum on StackExchange.

Comment: If it sounds nasty, turn it down and it'll be fine.

Comment: @user_1818839: How on Earth would turning down an underpowered amplifier help the situation? And I was asking about loss of sound quality. No one said it sounds *nasty*.

Comment: @JonathanWood Simple. The way an underpowered amp destroys speakers is by clipping, when overdriven. So, if it is clipping, (which sounds nasty), reduce the output level until it's operating cleanly again. Alternatively, if it's working at the level you need without clipping, then it isn't underpowered for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lower power amplifier cannot damage the speakers or amplifier, the speakers will just not be as loud.

I had a look at the speakers' manual and it's far from clear what the 200W rating actually means, they say it is not a power rating and go off into a gobbledegook analogy about car engines and state troopers. Normally speakers and amplifiers, when properly rated, are rated in Watts RMS, which is the amount of power the speakers can dissipate in a sustained fashion without burning out. It doesn't relate to program material but is at least a well defined number. They don't specify that, but seem to be implying that you should use an amplifier up to 200W but the RMS rating is (I infer) well below that so the presumption is that the program being listened to will have a much lower average power output. I very much doubt they'd last long with a 200W amp ramming highly compressed audio into them.

But as it is, your amp should be fine with these speakers.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, getting good information is not always straight forward. Silly me for assuming the amp, being rated at 100 watts, assumed 6-ohm speakers.